# JQuery Ajax complete not firing for rails remote link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following remote link_to tag defined like so:

```
 =link_to "",  {:action => "destroy", :id => user.id}, :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "delete-icon"
```

This works fine but I want to hook into the jquery 1.5.1 ajax events to provide notification to the user.  I have to event handlers defined below, the ajax:before event fires but none of the others do.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.  I am testing this on safari 5

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.delete-icon').bind("ajax:before",  //fires
                function(){
               $('#progress').show(300);
    });

    $('.delete-icon').bind('ajax:after', //does not fire
        function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("complete!");
    });

});
```

Comment: which jquery-ujs version were you using at the time?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to bind to "complete" instead of "ajax:after". If you prefer to only be noticed when it succeed, try "success" instead.

Comment: I have tried them all, the only one that fires is ajax:before.  I am very confused.  I am fairly sure that rails.js is not overriding them.

Comment: I got the same error as you. Only ajax:beforeSend get called, ajax:complete and ajax:success, even ajax:error not called. Have you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I recommend using "complete" and your function must accept 4 parameters

```
$('.delete-icon').bind('ajax:complete', //this will work
    function(event, data, status, xhr) { //note parametes
        alert("complete!");
});
```

You might want to read this article for additional info [Jquery-ujs and Jquery Trigger](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/05/11/jquery-ujs-and-jquery-trigger.html)